# Recovering formatted Microsoft Storage Space Raid-5

Tags: storage, raid5, data-recovery, format

I have accidentally formatted my Storage Space. The setup is 3 units of USB 3.0 Hard drives with 4TB each.
Total 7.4Tb of storage available.

I have used Active File Recovery with no success.It finds my files and directories. But the recovered files are corrupt.

No write operations or any files have been stored on that disc. So the files shouldn't be corrupt.

I think the problem is the virtual recovery Raid-5 disk that I'm trying to setup.

1. I need to setup the virtual raid with right disk order, (6 combinations)
2. Right configuration of Left/Right & Sync/Async.
3. Stripe size

Does anyone know what is the right setup for Microsoft Storage Space?

Comment: Also PLEASE don't use R5, especially on large slow disks, consider R5 dead, nobody uses in more.

Answer (score 2):

Storage Spaces use a propriety form of software RAID and so it seems that all conventional approaches to recovery are useless.

In any case, try this tool: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk to at least recover data from storage spaces.

Also, you can try to use EaseUs: https://www.easeus.com/download.htm